# ¿Cual sería el xml final para hacer la prueba del web service de la Dian en SoapUI?

Tags: xml, soapui

Realizo la prueba con el siguiente xml

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security 
     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
     xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>94768897-e55e-494d-a4fd-ba2b199501d2</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">fc8eac422eba16e22ffd8c6f94b3f40a6e38162c</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
         <rep:NIT>9999999</rep:NIT>
         <rep:InvoiceNumber>808080808</rep:InvoiceNumber>
         <rep:IssueDate>2015-07-16T00:00:00</rep:IssueDate>
         <rep:Document>cid:1010204007416</rep:Document>
      </rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Me sale este error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: Error al auntenticar username/password [94768897-e55e-494d-a4fd-ba2b199501d2]</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Dice que Error al autenticar username/password, ahora la duda es como debo poner el pwd que tengo para autenticarme en el sitio de la Dian

El usuario esta bien, es el identificador unico del software provisto por la DIAN
El password es el resultado de usar SHA-256 sobre la contraseña que se configuro en el sitio de la DIAN.

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer la invocación del service web de la Dian: http://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co:80/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Para recibir ayuda más fácil, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes. También puedes hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Por favor, pon el mensaje de error completo en tu pregunta. Así mismo, si tienes info como la del comentario, puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que sea necesario usando el enlace `editar` que está justo bajo la pregunta. Por último: el enlace que pusiste está roto. Trata de poner la info relevante EN la pregunta para que no dependa de enlaces externos

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo por las sugerencias, soy nuevo por estos lados

Comment: Y muy bienvenido, colega coterráneo. Espero que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando la [documentación](https://www.dian.gov.co/fizcalizacioncontrol/herramienconsulta/FacturaElectronica/Factura%20Electrnica/Nuevo%20servicio%20Web%20Consulta%20del%20Resultado%20de%20Transacciones.pdf) de DIAN (impuestos nacionales de Colombia) y habría que incluir en el header de tu mensaje SOAP, los datos de autenticación, pues usan WS-Security.

En la documentación dan este ejemplo:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security 
     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
     xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>21825470-9229-457d-b7bd-460fd38a7a3f</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
            6361b7b5322acb07ced00a35a85a4cc5183da3a42ede0b07f578067a18425a55
            </wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Este encabezado debe ir en tu mensaje. Así mismo, ten en cuenta que la respuesta va firmada (el header de la respuesta incluye datos de esta firma)

Comment: Sale este error ahora: "<u>JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available."

Comment: @CarlosFabregas Revisando por ahí, sólo encuentro que es una excepción de JBoss por una [mala configuración](https://jbossadventure.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/spring-ws-and-exception-handling-33-endpoint-configuration-issues/) del manejo de excepciones. Suena a que algo falla en el WS-security pero habría que revisar qué. Evita usar espacios entre los tags del password, revisa que el username sea correcto...

Comment: @CarlosFabregas ten en cuenta también el tipo de password, relee la documentación para encontrar cualquier diferencia con tu implementación. Si definitivamente no hay, edita tu pregunta y pon lo que intentaste _debajo de tu primer intento_ para ver qué más probar.

Comment: gracias por las respuestas, bueno te cuento, según leí el username es el que genera el app de la Dian, ya voy a editar la pregunta para que veas como quedo..., por otro lado el pwd es en SHA-256